# Passing an Array by reference in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, reference

I'm new to C and I have a doubt.

Since C functions create local copies of it's arguments, I'm wondering why the following code works as expected:

```c
void function(int array[]){

    array[0] = 4;
    array[1] = 5;
    array[2] = 6;   
}

int main(){

    int array[] = {1,2,3};

    function(array);

    printf("%d %d %d",array[0],array[1],array[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

With the line output being 4 5 6.

Why does this work while the following doesn't?

```c
void function(int integer){

    integer = 2;
}

int main(){

    int integer = 1;

    function(integer);

    printf("%d",integer);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is just 1 in this case.

Short version: Why can functions modify the values of their parent variables if they are passed as array?

Thank you all!

Comment: Anyone who thinks that arrays are "really" pointers needs to read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/). Quick summary: No, they're not.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that arrays tend to decay into pointers.

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int* p = a; // valid: p is now the address of a[0]
a = p;  // NOT valid.

printf("a = %p\n", a);
printf("p = %p\n", p); // prints same address as a
```

`a` and `p` will print the same value.

Contrary to what others have said, `a` is *not* a pointer, it can simply decay to one. http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html

In your first `function()` what gets passed is the address of the array's first element, and the function body dereferences that. Infact, the compiler is treating the function prototype as this:

```
void function(int* array /*you wrote int array[]*/){
    array[0] = 4;
    array[1] = 5;
    array[2] = 6;   
}

function(&array[0]);
```

This has to happen because you said "array of unknown size" (int array[]). The compiler could not guarantee to deduce the amount of stack required to pass by value, so it decays to a pointer.

---- Edit ----

Lets combine both your examples and use more distinctive names to make things clearer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func1(int dynArray[]) {
    printf("func1: dynArray = %p, &dynArray[0] = %p, dynArray[0] = %d\n",
             dynArray, &dynArray[0], dynArray[0]);
}

void func2(int* intPtr) {
    printf("func2: intPtr = %p, &intPtr[0] = %p, intPtr[0] = %d\n",
             intPtr, &intPtr[0], intPtr[0]);
}

void func3(int intVal) {
    printf("func3: intVal = %d, &intValue = %p\n",
             intVal, &intVal);
}

int main() {
    int mainArray[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int mainInt = 10;

    printf("mainArray = %p, &mainArray[0] = %p, mainArray[0] = %d\n",
             mainArray, &mainArray, mainArray[0]);
    func1(mainArray);
    func2(mainArray);

    printf("mainInt = %d, &mainInt = %p\n",
             mainInt, &mainInt);
    func3(mainInt);

    return 0;
}
```

Live demo at ideone: http://ideone.com/P8C1f4

```
mainArray = 0xbf806ad4, &mainArray[0] = 0xbf806ad4, mainArray[0] = 1
func1: dynArray = 0xbf806ad4, &dynArray[0] = 0xbf806ad4, dynArray[0] = 1
func2: intPtr = 0xbf806ad4, &intPtr[0] = 0xbf806ad4, intPtr[0] = 1

mainInt = 10, &mainInt = 0xbf806acc
func3: intVal = 10, &intValue = 0xbf806ad0
```

In `func1` and `func2` "dynArray" and "intPtr" are local variables, but they are pointer variables into which they receive the address of "mainArray" from main.

This behavior is specific to arrays. If you were to put the array inside a struct, then you would be able to pass it by value.

Comment: What gets passed is not the address of the array, it's the address of the array's first element. (Same memory address, different type.)

Comment: So, for example, when we use array[1], is that [1] implicitly dereferencing the pointer already?

Also, I've tried to initialize the array as int array[3] and also used in array[3] inside the function header, but it still prints 4 5 6, even though the compiler could guarantee the amount of stack required to pass everything by value. Am I missing something? Thank you!

Comment: @Rogério, given "int a[]={1,2,3}", the expression a[1] is precisely equivalent to *(a+1). That is, "a" is the address of the first int, "a+1" is the address of the int immediately following, and "*(a+1)" is the int pointed to by that expression. The subscript operator can be thought of as syntactic sugar.

As for your second point, see my earlier comment. You cannot pass an array by value in C. It doesn't matter that the compiler has enough information to do it. That's not how the language is defined.

Comment: I reworded the answer slightly: The decay *has* to happen in the case of a dynamically sized array for that reason, but it also happens in other cases.

Also added some additional explanation at the ---- edit ----.

Comment: Does this imply a statically sized array would be passed by value?  Or _only_ when wrapped in a struct?

Comment: @Max Passing a statically sized array, `void fn(char in[8]); char c[8]; fn(c);`, cause a decay to pointer. As would a typedef alias. It's only passed by value when passed as part of a struct. See https://godbolt.org/g/nkIBAm

Answer (score 3):

**An array passed to a function is converted  to a pointer**. When you pass a pointer as argument to a function, you simply give the address of the variable in the memory. So when you modify the value of the cell of the array, you edit the value under the address given to the function.

When you pass a simple integer to a function, the integer is copied in the stack, when you modify the integer within the function, you modify the copy of the integer, not the original.

### Reminder of the different kinds of memory in C

In C, we can use three types of memory :

- **the stack, used for local variables and functions calls**: when we create a variable in main(), we use the stack to store the variable, and when a function is called, the parameters given to the method are register in the stack. When we exit a function, we "pop" these parameters to return to the original state, with the used variable before the call of the function. (anecdote: a stackoverflow is when we hack the stack to use previous variables in a function without passing it as parameters)
- **the heap which corresponds to the dynamicly allocated memory**: when we need large amount of data, we use this heap because the stack is limited to a few megabytes.
- **the code where the program instructions are stored**

In the case of this array passed by a function, which is a pointer (address to an other variable), it is stored in the stack, when we call the function, we copy the pointer in the stack.

In the case of the integer, it is also stored in the stack, when we call the function, we copy the integer.

If we want to modify the integer, we can pass the address of the integer to modify the value under the pointer, like this:

```
void function(int *integer)
{
    *integer = 2;
}

int main()
{
    int integer = 1;
    function(&integer);

    printf("%d", integer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, an array is not a pointer. An array expression, in most contexts, is implicitly converted to a pointer to the array object's first element.

Comment: "converted to a pointer" - false, and likely to be confusing to programmers coming from languages like C#. An array in C/C++ is two things. It is a block of memory containing N instances of a given type, and a pointer to that memory. The ABI provides no mechanism to forward such data so you can only achieve it by perfectly matching the argument you wish to pass - either an explicit, hard coded fingerprint or in C++ a template to make one for you. `int f(char (&arg)[64])` or `template<class T, size_t N> int f(T (&arg)[N])`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between 'pass by reference' and 'pass by value'

Pass by reference leads to a location in the memory where pass by value passes the value directly, an array variable is always an refference, so it points to a location in the memory. Integers will pass by value by default

Answer (score 1):

In the first code, you are passing the address of the array pointing to the top element in the array. So, when you modify the value in the function and return to the main function you are still accessing the same array which is in the same address. This is called pass by reference.

However, in the second case, the value of the integer is copied from the main function to the called function. In other words, the two integers are in different address in the memory. So modifying one does not modify the other.

Answer (score 0):

The array name is a pointer to the first element in the array. In the first code sample you have passed a pointer to the memory location containing the first array element. In the second code sample you have passed an integer by value so it has nothing to do with the local variable named "integer"

check that link

**Pass by reference and pass by value**

[Pass by Reference / Value in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410593/pass-by-reference-value-in-c)

Comment: The array name _is converted to a pointer_ to the first element of the array in most contexts. The array name is not a pointer.