# Pass by reference an array of pointers in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I think to pass my array in a wrong way by reference cause I have lot of warning for its. Could you help me?

```
void func (char **array[], char b){
*array[0]=&b;
}

int main () {

char *array_in_main[SIZE];
char b_in_main='b';
func (*array_in_main, b_in_main);
return 0;

}
```

Yes, I know. It's a no-sense example but my doubt is on syntax. Check it please!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What part do you need help with? What are the errors and warnings you get?

Comment: You can't use the address of a local variable outside of its scope.

Answer (score 5):

You have a view problems here.

First you passing the wrong type to your function. If you want to modify an array in a function you do not have to pass it with a pointer to the array since the array decays to a pointer to its first element.

Second you attempt to use the address of `b` which is a local variable and its scope ends with the function `func`, you can not use it outside.

This code will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

void func (char *array[], char *b)
{
    array[0]=b;
}

int main () 
{
    char *array_in_main[SIZE];
    char b_in_main='b';
    func (array_in_main, &b_in_main);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok but in this way is array_in_main still modified when func() ends in the main? I don't understand if pass array in function is like pass a simple variable or not.

Comment: @ilacollie Yes it is still modified.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in **C** are broken down into a pointer to the first element when used as a parameter.

Just pass the array itself.  There's no need for a pointer to it.

Also, like **Osiris** said, you can't use the address of a local variable outside its scope.

```
void func (char *array[], char b){  /* Changed &b to b */
    array[0][0]=b; /* Changed array[0] to array[0][0], assuming that array is a 2D array */
}
int main () {
    char *array_in_main[SIZE];
    char b_in_main='b';
    func (array_in_main, b_in_main); /* Changed *array_in_main to array_in_main */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `array[0][0]=b;` The pointer was never initialized, so i think this leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: true, though i did use `*char[]` for 2d char arrays often, hence my reasoning

Answer (score 0):

This is probably closer to what you're trying to do, no?

In addition to the compilation issues (already explained in [Tau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062420/4288486) and in [Osiris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062441/4288486)), it's worth noting that arrays are already pointers themselves.

Just declare in main `char array_in_main[SIZE]`. Afterwards you can just specify `char array[]` as the argument and pass `array_in_main` directly. What is passed to the function is the address of the first position in the array `&(array_in_main[0])`, so the array can be effectively updated from the function.

The code:

```
#define SIZE 10

void func(char array[], char b) {
  array[0] = b;
}

int main () {
  char array_in_main[SIZE];
  char b_in_main='x';
  func(array_in_main, b_in_main);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the mechanism of how an `array` is passed to a function in C programming language. When you pass an array to a function in C, pointer (address) to first element of the array is passed to the function and since you have a reference to it, you can modify the content of the array in the function (but you can't change the memory location to which array is pointing). I recommend to have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646512/passing-an-array-by-reference-in-c).

The program below has two functions. `rightFunc` function is a simple and correct approach to achieve what you have been trying to do. However, I have provided `func` which shows the way of passing pointer (or reference) to an array of pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100

void rightFunc(char *array[], char *b)
{
    array[0] = b;
}

void func(char *(*array)[], char *b)
{
    (*array)[0] = b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char *array_in_main[SIZE];
    char b_in_main = 'b';

    func(&array_in_main, &b_in_main);
    printf("Character is %c\r\n", *array_in_main[0]);

    b_in_main = 'c';
    rightFunc(array_in_main, &b_in_main);
    printf("Character is %c\r\n", *array_in_main[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to point out one error in your program. You can get address of local variable (`automatic storage class`) but that address will not be valid outside the function (when function has exited). To rectify the issue in your program, I have modified the functions to take `pointer to char` in your program.